# IIS: get system CPU usage from web api application

Tags: iis, wmi, cpu-usage, wmic

I have to create a small service, to show health status of the machine (Windwos service).

I created a very small and simple aspnet app, that returns this data.
It works fine when I run the app from command line (using  `dotnet` command), But when I run it as a IIS site, the `cpu` method doesn't returns any value.

Thanks for any help, and sorry for my bad English.

This is the code:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[Route("/")]
public sealed class SystemHealthController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("cpu")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetCpu()
            => await WmicMetricsClient.Cpu().ConfigureAwait(false);

    [HttpGet("memory")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetMemory()
                => await WmicMetricsClient.Memory();
}

public static class WmicMetricsClient
{
    public static async Task<string> Memory()
    {
        var output = await GetCommandLineOutputAsync(
            fileName: "wmic",
            arguments: "OS get FreePhysicalMemory,TotalVisibleMemorySize /Value");

        return output;
    }

    public static async Task<string> Cpu()
    {
        var output = await GetCommandLineOutputAsync(
            fileName: "wmic",
            arguments: "cpu get loadpercentage /Value");

        return output;
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetCommandLineOutputAsync(string fileName, string arguments)
    {
        var info = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            Arguments = arguments,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        };

        using var process = Process.Start(info);
        return await process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can refer to: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10258/How-to-Get-CPU-Usage-of-Processes-and-Threads

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 A command like `wmic` is very likely to require certain permissions, and a web app running on IIS might not meet those requirements.

Comment: @TheobaldDu, It is very very old, .NET 1, I will try it, but i need a solution for .net core.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have the solution:

In the Computer Management>System Tools>Local Usesr and groups>Groups.

then, I click on "Perfomance Monitor Users" group, and add IIS `Apppool\MYAPPPOOL`.